# Are symlinks recognized by iCloud?

Tags: macos, icloud, dropbox

I would love to keep all of my personal files (docs, photos, videos, music) in my user folder *where they're supposed to be*, and still have them on iCloud for my mobile devices. I thought of putting symlinks that point to the user folders in the iCloud folder in `~/Library/Mobile Documents`. Does anyone have authoritative information to tell if these symlink targets will be synced with iCloud similar to the way symlinks can be used with Dropbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, symlinks work fine with iCloud. I have been using them since before the introduction of iCloud Drive using manual manipulation of the Mobile Documents folder and developer.apple.com, and this still works since the introduction of iCloud Drive.

Comment: Do you mean you put the symlink in the `Mobile Documents` folder that is linked to the user folder or put the actual docs in the `Mobile Documents` folder and the symlink in the user folder? It doesn't seem to be working for me.